# Best way to swap images from a stack : src, visibility, z-index... something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have 60 images. I want to display one image at a time and when the user pans it will display the next or the previous one depending on the pan's direction.
Simple example to explain my thought :

http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel#demo

For now I load and append all my images to the DOM (`img` html tag... maybe as css `background-image` is better in my case) and I swap between them with the `visibility` attribute : hidden / visible.
It's working fine.

Second option : Same as before but I play with the `z-index` to put the desired image to the foreground.

Third option : just one image and I swap the `src` attribute.

**EDIT 1** : images are intended to be displayed fullscreen and are 720p.

**EDIT 2** : Loading the 60 images at the beginning is not really an issue... if I want more images I will load them as I need them.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did not know about codereview, thank you... feel free to ask for closing, I'll relocate if it's the best for stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Z-index` is much more slower than `visibility`.

If you want to browse a stack of images (hundreds of 720p images) go for the hidden/visible.

I would be interested to know why tough !

Answer (score 1):

I would place all images, positioned absolute in a container. Each image with a z-index of 1, except the first has the class `top`. The `top` class has `z-index: 2`.

In jQuery, when you click the img with class `top` it removes the class, finds the next element and adds the `top` class to that, each click making the next image visible.

Swapping the src or background image is going to require further loading on each click. Load everything, display accordingly with z-index.

Comment: Thanks for the top jquery thing... did not know about it. But I'd like to have more control (going n to n+2 for example). I understand that it's better to load them all but why z-index more than visibility ?

Comment: You can easily go to next, or nextnext in jQuery. I only thought of the z-index because then there will be a small chance for visible glitching. Say you use visibility, and the visible one disappears before the next one is made visible? You have a briefly empty area.

If you code it to change to visible before hiding the last one, you have two visible at the same time and have to code to make sure you are properly selecting the old image to hide, not the newly visible one. Using the z-index just seemed simpler :)

Comment: I change this answer from accepted to not because at first it works but when you put load (hundreds of 720p images) on the z-index swapping, it becomes awfully slow. visibility is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the first option is the better one. But regarding performance issues, instead of loading every images at once, load only the first ones. On pan event load the next image bundle and so on.

Comment: See my edit 2 about the loading. "Maybe" is a bit light, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you shouln't use the method with visibility, display, visibility or z-index: it would slow down the loading of your page, because 60 images would be loaded at the same time.

I tried the following, and it worked for clicking, although just in one direction (you can also add the buttons "back" an "forward"):

```
<img id="img" onmouseup="toggle()" scr="1.png" style="border-style:solid;padding:3px;border-width:1px;" />
```

javascript:

```
var i = 1;

function toggle() {
  i++;
  if(i==61) i = 1;
  document.getElementById('img').src = i+".png";
}
```

Now you just have to put the images called "1.png, 2.png, 3.png, ... , 60.png" to the folder.

Comment: I don't mind the loading at the beginning I will handle it with a progressbar or something.